# Python: Finding Maximum of New values in a csv

Tags: python, csv

So I have a csv file and I am editing each row's budget column to be converted into USD so I can properly compare budgets, as most of the films are denominated in native currency.

I would like to know the maximum the column after changing the values for the budget in the csv.

```
import csv

csvfile = open('FinalDCutf8.csv', encoding = "utf-8")
reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)

UK_conv = 1.24136

for row in reader:
    if row['country'] == 'USA':
        if row['budget'] != '':
            print(row['budget'])
    elif row['country'] == 'UK':
        if row['budget'] != 'N/A':
            floatconv = float(row['budget'])
            floatconv = floatconv*UK_conv
            print(floatconv)
```

This is basically what I have so far, and there are many more of these for each country in the csv file. I would just like to know how to find the maximum.

[MyCSV](https://unisydneyedu-my.sharepoint.com/personal/zsan9112_uni_sydney_edu_au/_layouts/15/guestaccess.aspx?docid=00558e70082c94381be185ed3f5a00c04&authkey=AezC4WCxqGtU_jb3CA4pTUQ&expiration=2017-07-26T13%3A00%3A42.000Z)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For instance:.

```
max_budget = 0.0
for ...
    budget = float(row['budget'])

    if max_budget < budget:
         max_budget = budget
```